# How to get radius value in jqplot bubble chart

Tags: tooltip, jqplot, bubble-chart

```
function extender() {
    this.cfg.highlighter = {
        show : true,
        tooltipLocation:'n',
        tooltipContentEditor:tooltipContentEditor
    };
}

function tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {                 
    var label = plot.series[seriesIndex]["label"];
    var radius = plot.series[seriesIndex]["radius"];
    console.log('label :::'+label); //ABC
    console.log('radius :::'+radius); //undefined
}
```

getting `radius` value is `undefined` but getting label value. here something wrong `plot.series[seriesIndex]["radius"]`.

also try `plot.series[seriesIndex][2]`

**Note :** I am using primefaces so `this.cfg.highlighter` is used.

give your valuable suggestions. Happy Coding.